# how to create count distinct values in a column in Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a data as below

```
 Mode   Function
mode_1    A
mode_2    B
mode_1    A
mode_3    A
mode_3    B
```

Expected Answer

```
Mode     distinct.count
mode_1      1
mode_2      1
mode_3      2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
My Measure = DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Function])
```